# How to unwrap an optional into a variable and then use that variable in the next iteration of a while loop?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a method below called createNotifications() in which I try to do some fancy stuff when the recurrence of an alarm is `daily`. I first call self.createNotificationForToday(), which goes fine, and then start a while loop and call self.createNotificationForTomorrowAndReturnNewDateComponents() in each iteration, each time returning the new date components and using it as the input for the next iteration. This allows me to call one method each time and every time, iterate to "tomorrow" and create a notification for that day. The problem is with this part:

```
var newDateComponents = dateComponents
while numberOfCreatableNotifications > 0 {
    guard var newDateComponents = self.createNotificationForTomorrowAndReturnNewDateComponents(dateComponents: newDateComponents) else {
         os_log("Could not unwrap newDateComponents in createNotifications() in Alarm.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
         return
    }
    numberOfCreatableNotifications = numberOfCreatableNotifications - 1
}
```

What I'm attempting to do is reinitialize the `newDateComponents` variable each time I go through the while loop and call the createNotificationForTomorrowAnd...() method, and use those newDateComponents as input for the next call to that method. Is there something fundamentally wrong with how I'm trying to do this? Is there a better way?

---

createNotifications():

```
private func createNotifications(dateComponents: DateComponents) {

    if recurrence == .today {
        createNotificationForToday(dateComponents: dateComponents)
    } else if recurrence == .tomorrow {
        let _ = createNotificationForTomorrowAndReturnNewDateComponents(dateComponents: dateComponents)
    } else if recurrence == .daily {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.getPendingNotificationRequests { (notifications) in
            var numberOfCreatableNotifications = 64 - notifications.count
            self.createNotificationForToday(dateComponents: dateComponents)
            var newDateComponents = dateComponents
            while numberOfCreatableNotifications > 0 {
                guard var newDateComponents =
                        self.createNotificationForTomorrowAndReturnNewDateComponents(dateComponents: newDateComponents) else {
                    os_log("Could not unwrap newDateComponents in createNotifications() in Alarm.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
                    return
                }
                numberOfCreatableNotifications = numberOfCreatableNotifications - 1
            }
        }
    } else {}

}
```

---

createNotificationForToday():

```
private func createNotificationForToday(dateComponents: DateComponents) {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Random Alarm"
    content.subtitle = "It's time!"
    content.body = self.note
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)

    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    center.add(request) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error \(String(describing: error))")
        }
    }

}
```

---

createNotificationForTomorrowAndReturnNewDateComponents():

```
private func createNotificationForTomorrowAndReturnNewDateComponents(dateComponents: DateComponents) -> DateComponents? {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Random Alarm"
    content.subtitle = "It's time!"
    content.body = self.note
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    guard let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents) else {
        os_log("Could not unwrap date in createNotificationForTomorrow() in Alarm.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return nil
    }
    guard let tomorrow = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date) else {
        os_log("Could not unwrap tomorrow in createNotificationForTomorrow() in Alarm.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return nil
    }
    let newDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .timeZone, .hour, .minute], from: tomorrow)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newDateComponents, repeats: false)

    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    center.add(request) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error \(String(describing: error))")
        }
    }

    return newDateComponents

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of a variable created by a `guard` statement is the block that contains the `guard` statement, which is the body of your `while` loop.

This means that the `newDateComponents` you are creating with your `guard` statement is not the same as the `newDateComponents` you created outside the `while` and the inner `newDateComponents` will be discarded after each iteration of the `while` loop.

You don't actually need the `guard` statement; you can build the unwrap into your `while`:

```
var newDateComponents: DateComponents? = dateComponents
while numberOfCreatableNotifications > 0, let currentDateComponents = newDateComponents {
    newDateComponents = self.createNotificationForTomorrowAndReturnNewDateComponents(dateComponents: currentDateComponents) 
    numberOfCreatableNotifications -= 1
}
if numberOfCreateableNotifications > 0 {
    os_log("Could not create all notifications
}
```

You can probably refactor this to be a bit more efficient and have one less function:

- Use a `Calendar` property so that you don't need to keep instantiating the calendar
- Have a function to return "tomorrow"
- Have a function to schedule a notification

```
let calendar = Calendar.autoUpdatingCurrent

private func createNotifications(dateComponents: DateComponents) {

    switch (recurrence) {
        case .today:
            createNotification(for: dateComponents)
        case .tomorrow:
            createNotification(for: day(after: dateComponents))
        case .daily:
           let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
           center.getPendingNotificationRequests { (notifications) in
               var numberOfCreatableNotifications = 64 - notifications.count
               var currentDay: DateComponents? = dateComponents
               while numberOfCreatableNotifications > 0, current = currentDay {
                   createNotification(for: current)
                   currentDay = day(after: current)
                   numberOfCreateableNotification -= 1
               }  
               if numberOfCreateableNotifications > 0 {
                   os_log("Could not create all notifications", type: .debug)
               }
            }                          
    }
}


private func createNotification(for dateComponents: DateComponents) {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Random Alarm"
    content.subtitle = "It's time!"
    content.body = self.note
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)

    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    center.add(request) { (error) in
        if let err = error {
            print("error \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}



private func day(after dateComponents: DateComponents) -> DateComponents? {

    guard let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents), 
          let tomorrow = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)
    else {
        os_log("Could not calculate tomorrow in Alarm.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return nil
    }
    let newDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .timeZone, .hour, .minute], from: tomorrow)
    return newDateComponents

}
```

One final note, it would probably be nicer to pass `Date` instances rather than `DateComponent` instances and convert to `DateComponent` once when you need to actually schedule the notification.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed to see. The only problems:
1. Getting `Value of optional type 'DateComponents?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'DateComponents'` error on line `createNotification(for: day(after: dateComponents))`. How best to fix that?
2. `current` isn't defined anywhere. Can I just initialize that anywhere above the while loop?
3. `while numberOfCreatableNotifications > 0, current = currentDay` doesn't seem to be playing nicely with the compiler. Should it be `current == currentDay`?
4. How do I unwrap `current` for `createNotification(for: current)`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly bind to the variable `newDateComponents` from the
outer scope in the guard-statement. You can bind to a new variable and
then assign that to `newDateComponents`:

```
var newDateComponents = dateComponents
while numberOfCreatableNotifications > 0 {
    guard let nextDateComponents =
        self.createNotificationForTomorrowAndReturnNewDateComponents(dateComponents: newDateComponents) else {
            os_log("Could not unwrap newDateComponents in createNotifications() in Alarm.swift", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            return
    }
    newDateComponents = nextDateComponents
    numberOfCreatableNotifications = numberOfCreatableNotifications - 1
}
```